# How to show record made by tinyMCE?

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I use tinyMCE to input the blog content record. i write this:

> This is my new entry

i format it with justify and heading 1

then i display it, but the result is:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">This is my new entry</h1>
```

how to show it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce adds html tags to all the text that you enter in it. By default it adds `<p>` to all the text that you enter and save.You need to use the function `strip_tags()` in PHP to remove the html tags.

Example:

```
$a = "<h1 style="text-align: center;">This is my new entry</h1>"; //this data is have assigned for demo you can get it from any place
echo strip_tags($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

$text = '

Test paragraph.

Other text';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow

and 
echo strip_tags($text, '

');

//output :
//Test paragraph. Other text
//

Test paragraph.

Other text